# Laravel 5.2 Auth::check() is not working even when Auth::attempt() succeeds

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
public function login($local=false,$data=[])
{

    $validator = Validator::make(($local)?$data:Request::all(), [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Response::json(array('status'=>'0','message'=>'Invalid parameters'));
    }

    if(Auth::attempt(($local)?$data:Request::all()))
    {
        //dd(Auth::user());
        return Response::json(array('status'=>'1','message'=>'User logged in successfully'));
    }
        return Response::json(array('status'=>'1','message'=>'User log in failed'));

}
```

this works and shows successfully logged in, but when i tried accessing the details of the authenticated user, it returns null.

```
if(!Auth::check())
{
    return Response::json(array('status'=>'0','message'=>'User not logged in'));
}
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: are you using any API ? means request coming from same server or from any other location?

Comment: @Qazi yes i'm trying to develop an api controller, i'm running it on my localhost.

Comment: What do you use as you session driver?

Comment: hi @naneri i'm using file as session driver

Comment: Are you always doing a dd when you complete the auth attempt? If you don't return a response the session data won't be set correctly.

Comment: Is this all inside the `web` middleware in the `routes.php` file? This is needed to actually use the sessions.

Comment: @MattMcDonald no i actually used it for testing, updated :)

Comment: @James not its not inside the web middleware, is it compulsory to do that? since it is mentioned that "web middleware group is automatically applied to your default routes.php file by the RouteServiceProvider"

Comment: @ShibuMurugan As you're returning JSON, does this work for you when you try it as a standard POST request? I copied your login function and after modifying the Request portion to work correctly had no problems once a successful authentication was made. Have you so far been using your local variation? If so, perhaps what happens after that returns relates to the problem?

Comment: @James As of the most recent versions of Laravel 5.2 you actually don't want to use the web middleware group in your own routes file as this will cause it to be loaded twice which can cause issues of its own. github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12022

Comment: @MattMcDonald yes it works for me, i just did it for login with correct user role, actually there is no errors or failed login, everything works successfully, the issue is once after login using attempt, in other requests it shows the Auth::check() is false. But everything works fine if i'm using artisan way " php artisan make:auth ".

Comment: @ShibuMurugan Are you able to share some fuller code? It's likely something to do with how something is happening elsewhere in the app, but tricky to pinpoint what that might be.

Answer (score 0):

`Auth::check()` will work if request coming from same server
eg: `www.laraapi.com`

As per my understanding, you have to make some token based authentication, means

```
username=>'testuser',
password=>'123456987',
'userSecrectToken'=>'asd88225asdaweqs8899eqweiou'
```

once user is authenticated, pass secret token with userid/username and request type

eg:

```
'username'=>'testuser',
'userSecrectToken'=>'asd88225asdaweqs8899eqweiou'
'requestType'=>'getUserOrders',
```